# Set up Nginx for rtmp streaming, and Apache2 streams OK too?

Tags: nginx, apache2, rtmp

I have been testing out video streaming from my website.
I run a web server from my house on a machine running Debian-10.3.0 (buster).
It uses Apache-2.4.38 to serve the web pages.
So in setting up video streaming, I used nginx to keep everything separate.
Apache listens on port 80 and 443, nginx listens on 81 and will use 444.

```
$ sudo apt install nginx libnginx-mod-rtmp ffmpeg obs-studio
```

The nginx configuration file is at /usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf :

```
load_module /usr/local/libexec/nginx/ngx_stream_module.so;
load_module /usr/local/libexec/nginx/ngx_rtmp_module.so;
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
}

http {
    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    gzip on;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}

server {
    listen 81;
    server_name www.davekimble.net;
        location / {
            root /home/dk/www/davekimble.net/public_html;
            index index.html index.htm;
        }
    }

rtmp {
    server {
        listen 1935;
        chunk_size 4096;
        application live {
            live on;
            record off;  
        }
    }
}
```

This seems to work OK, **but the surprising thing to me is that Apache video streams as well.
How can this be ?**

Apache is using the docroot path: /home/dk/www/davekimble.net/public_html/.
Nginx is using the same docroot.
I have seen a sentence somewhere saying that this changes things, but **I can find no mention of it in the wiki.**
There is a folder /stream in there holding all the .mp4 files.
There is a streaming.php which has links to all and the video files.

To test this out, go to http://davekimble.net/streamimg.php and click on a link.

UPDATE 1
to demonstrate that it is Apache doing the streaming, I shut the firewall's port 81 to nginx and then did :

```
# systemctl stop nginx
```

and it still works, without nginx running.

I have changed "stream.htm" to "streaming.php" which simply lists the files in the /stream/ folder.

UPDATE 2
In fact the "basic configuration" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf is unnecessary and I have removed it from the post. 
The "alternative configuration" in /usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf is needed.